# Wrong SQL Query, need to search two names from a single table

Tags: mysql

In my problem I have a traveling routes table, and a city table, the routes table shows your origin city and your destination city as city id's, and the city id's names are on another table.

I want to search all the routes that start from X city, for this, I made this query

```
    SELECT ciudad.nombre as Origen, 
ciudad.nombre as Destino, 
km as Distancia, 
rutas.km*rutas.precio_km as Precio, 
fecha as Fecha 
FROM rutas, ciudad where "Santiago"=ciudad.nombre and ciudad.id_ciudad=rutas.ciudad_or;
```

[image]

This is the result I get, note Origen = Destino

[image]

This is the Routes table, ciudad_or and ciudad_de are the from and to cities.

[image]

This is my cities table

But it will print the same city on my origin and my destination, I don't know how to make it show the correct destination (which is also an Id)

I'm searching the routes with a city name

Comment: Give us some sample data pls.

Comment: Not images. They can't be copied and pasted to create test tables. DDL that creates the tables and DML that populates them.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a double-join to your cities table for each respective...

```
SELECT
      r.id_ruta,
      r.cuidad_or,
      Orig.nombre as Origen,
      r.cuidad_de,
      Dest.nombre as Destino,
      any_other_columns...
   from
      Routes r
         join ciudad as Orig
            ON r.ciudad_or = Orig.id_ciudad
         join ciudad as Dest
            ON r.cuidad_de = Dest.id_ciudad
   where
          orig.nombre="Santiago"
      OR  dest.nombre="Santiago"
```

Now, doing an OR looking for either an origination or destination a better approach would be via a UNION of pre-qualifying something like

I would suggest TWO indexes on your cuidad table.  One on cuidad_or, another on cuidad_de

```
SELECT
      r.id_ruta,
      r.cuidad_or,
      Orig.nombre as Origen,
      r.cuidad_de,
      Dest.nombre as Destino,
      any_other_columns...
   from
      Routes r
         join ciudad as Orig
            ON r.ciudad_or = Orig.id_ciudad
         join ciudad as Dest
            ON r.cuidad_de = Dest.id_ciudad
   where
      orig.nombre="Santiago"
UNION
SELECT
      r.id_ruta,
      r.cuidad_or,
      Orig.nombre as Origen,
      r.cuidad_de,
      Dest.nombre as Destino,
      any_other_columns...
   from
      Routes r
         join ciudad as Orig
            ON r.ciudad_or = Orig.id_ciudad
         join ciudad as Dest
            ON r.cuidad_de = Dest.id_ciudad
   where
      dest.nombre="Santiago"
```

The union will work better on the individual indexes than trying to combine both into one. wow... bad with fingers tonight on mistyped column names, period and spacing... getting late.